# Error Message when trying to delete features in Feature Service Python API 1.7 for ArcGIS

Tags: python, api, arcgis

I am trying to delete features using the  delete_features method on the FeatureLayer Object and I keep getting the following error: `"This SqlTransaction has completed; it is no longer usable."`

The code is below. The error message seems to populate in the last line where="OBJECTID >=0", but I'm not a 100 sure if this is the problem. Unfortunately I'm not very good at programming.

```py
    gis = arcgis.GIS("http://gfcgis.maps.arcgis.com", "UserName", "Password") 
    feature_layer_item = gis.content.search(FeatureLayer, item_type = 'Feature Service')[0]
    flayers = feature_layer_item.layers
    flayer = flayers[0]
    flayer.delete_features(where="OBJECTID >= 0", rollback_on_failure=True)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Michael

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a zombie transaction. Check with your DBA if there's a query, most likely a Stored Procedure, which is being called when your code runs. This message usually shows up when the application code tries to do a commit on the DB after the SP has already committed.

That's the SQL Transaction which has already completed.

Comment: Thanks for you help Abhishek,

Comment: Thanks for your helping me to understand that error message Abhishek. Come to find out, it was a simple syntax error causing the issue. I didn't put quotations around 'True' for the rollback_on_failure parameter. I'm a little surprised it  didn't throw a syntax error instead of the "Sqltransaction message"

Answer (score 0):

Come to find out, it was a simple syntax error causing the issue. I didn't put quotations around 'True' for the rollback_on_failure parameter.